# How to install PHP curl extension on wamp server WIN XP?

Tags: php, curl, windows-xp, libcurl

I have WAMP SERVER,PHP 5.3.0 and Apache server 2.2.11 I want to download a suitable CURL lib version for it 
I studied the sites and found that this installation will not be easy it may not work if the version is not suitable please help me with details also I found here:

http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090827212635AAWBwZj

http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/curl-issue-for-wamp-server-t100949.html

but I'm not sure to get the perfect result cause my version is different

also I have another problem if I can not install it in a good way will my wamp server and databases go wrong or not?

Comment: dear members on wamp servers click on the icon then choose the extensions and then check the cURL extension which is named php_curl it will be installed easily;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running WAMPSERVER? If not, I would recommend doing so if you wouldn't miss your current WAMP environment -- it comes with CURL along with many other useful features.

Check it out here: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Cool tip. Is it with xdebug as well? I've seen many xdebug windows users here on SO that have problems installing. And PDO?

Comment: Jamie I have wamp server I can't unistall it I have programs and databases in there

Comment: maybe I must get back up of them and try yours but risky

Comment: There's not much risk at all. You should even be able to turn off your other server and run WAMP instead just to try it out. I say "should" because there may be some conflicts with multiple Apache services on Windows. I can't recall having any such problems myself, however.

Comment: Jamie I unistalled it but when I go to download it tells me this:We cannot send this file to your location. Please visit our our T7 page

Comment: would you please help me do you have it?Can you mail it to me?

Comment: it is very strange my country has filterations but I use VPN but still I can't get!

Comment: I'm creating account in source forge  now! maybe it will help!

Comment: My IP Address and Country are blocked I sent this ticket but I must wait how much?:"( it is 4:22 AM here still I didn't install it!

Comment: Are you on 32bit or 64bit Windows?

Comment: Jamie I am so tired I would be very happy if you have solution of this issue it is sadness for me veryvery much cause I really need this really really here is my Email:Nickparsa@gmail.com

Comment: I solved My problem:D I used that yahoo answer it worked for me! lol!

Comment: Wamp server has this extention by itself it suffices going to `PHP->PHP extensions->check the php_curl`

Answer (score 0):

open php.ini file and find  this line

> ;extension=php_curl.dll

remove ;

> extension=php_curl.dll

save file 
... 
still problem exists 
then check for this file

> php_curl.dll

in

> {wamp}\bin\php\php5.x.x\ext\

if it's not there than download it from internet and paste it to there

Restart Apache.